# Unexpected output on using puts() and printf() function

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a basic code on my Dev C++ IDE, but it gives an expected output-

```
printf("%d", printf("stackoverflow1"));
printf("%d", puts("stackoverflow2"));
puts(printf("stackoverflow3"));
```

the expected output should be:

> stackoverflow114stackoverflow2
>
> 14stackoverflow314

but the output I'm getting is:

> stackoverflow114stackoverflow2
>
> 0stackoverflow3

Can someone explain the inconsistency in the output ? I know that `puts` return a non negative number but why I'm getting a '0' everytime. Also in the last statement why is puts not printing the no of characters printed by `printf` ?

Comment: '0' is a non-negative number. It was never said it should be the number of characters printed.

Comment: `puts(printf("stackoverflow3"));` invokes UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- puts(), as you mentioned, only has to return a non-negative number on success. This means the compiler you are using gets to decide what is returned, as long as it follows this. Your compiler appears to have chosen 0.
- as 2501 mentioned, passing puts(const char * p ) an int is illegal, your compiler should have complained about it. puts() is supposed to print starting from p until it reaches a '\0' char, so the input has to be a pointer to a '\0' terminated string

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior. [puts()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) takes a `const char*` argument yet you pass it an `int`.

```
puts(printf("stackoverflow3"));
```

Enable warnings on your compiler and your code won't even compile.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("%d", printf("stackoverflow1"));
```

Printf returns an int (how much chars are printed = 14). Because the arguments of the outer printf have to be evaluated before the outer one can be evaluated, the string printed will bee "stackoverflow114"

```
printf("%d", puts("stackoverflow2"));
```

puts returns a "nonnegative value" (this is the only guarantee, the standard gives to you). In your case the nonnegative value is the int 14. The string "stackoverflow2\n" is printed by `puts` and the 14 is printed by `printf`.

```
puts(printf("stackoverflow3"));
```

`puts` takes an `const char*` as an argument and `printf` returns the number of chars printed (which is 14, again). Since `puts` takes a pointer, it may interpret the memory at address 14 as a string and output it (it might cancel compilation, too - most compilers will be 'glad' and cast this for you, along with a warning). This string seems to be empty (this might be sort of random). This line thus only prints "stackoverflow3" (in your case) and the outer puts only prints a random string (in your case "").

Comment: "it will interpret the memory at address 14 as a string " - your answer should note that this is a compiler extension (not a very good one either IMHO); in Standard C the code is ill-formed.